# How should I arrange the codec handlers in Netty?

Tags: java, netty, encoder, decoder

I have a little confused with the Netty codec, I know I need add some codes to the pipeline, but how should I arrange the encoder and decoders?  Can anybody give a simple explanation of the rules of how to arrange the encoder and decoders in a pipeline?

**the server side code:**

```
protected static void run() throws Exception {
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
    b.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
    b.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();               

            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("bufd",new 

                            ProtobufDecoder(PbConditions.Conditions.getDefaultInstance()));
            pipeline.addLast("servercodec",new HttpServerCodec());
            pipeline.addLast("aggegator",new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            pipeline.addLast(new MemcachedServiceHandler());
            pipeline.addLast("",new ProtobufEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("responseencoder",new HttpResponseEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("clientcodec",new HttpClientCodec());

        }
    });
    b.bind(IP, PORT).sync();

}
```